# FLV Player is going out of sync in IE and Chrome

Tags: flv

I have the following FLV player running on a site we're making, http://flv-player.net/, however, the audio goes out of sync with the video very quickly.

It seems ok in Firefox, just about...

Any ideas, or has anyone else experienced anything like this before?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

the answer to this was use Flow Player.